# With regards to a national insurance refund, what is my Work or Clock number?

Tags: united-kingdom, payroll-taxes, national-insurance

So i got a letter from hmrc (UK tax) letting me know I'm due for a refund, and on one of the bits I need to fill out it asks me for my "Work or Clock number" for each job I've had during the tax year.

I don't know what this is, and googling the term has yielded nothing.

What is it and how do I get hold of it?

[image]

The item in question is circled in green. 
Thanks.

Edit: for those of you saying to be careful and that it looks like a scam, here is the first page and the return address:
[image]
That address on top (at least the post code) is listed on the UK government website [see here](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/hm-revenue-customs/contact/national-insurance-enquiries-for-non-uk-residents).

Answer (score 12):

First, please make sure that this letter from HMRC is genuine and not some kind of scam. It probably is ok, but make sure that the return address you are sending to is a genuine HMRC address, e.g. by cross-checking with the HMRC website.

The work or clock number is probably just the unique reference your employer has for you and reports your payments to HMRC with. If you have a payslip it might be referred to as a "payroll number".

Comment: Thanks, that looks to be it. Do you know what the tax district is too and where I can find it? Does F285 sound correct?

Comment: It should be on your payslip. If there are 3 digits followed by "/F285", what you want is the *first* three digits, not the "285." Note the tax district may be a completely different location from where you actually work, if you are employed by a large company and/or one with many workplaces (e.g. a chain of shops may have only one tax district for the whole chain). If all else fails,ask HMRC, they should be able to tell you from your National Insurance number.https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/hm-revenue-customs/contact/income-tax-enquiries-for-individuals-pensioners-and-employees

Comment: "just the unique reference" - indeed, a large company may have 100 employees called "John Smith" for example. "Clock number" dates back to "clocking on and off" with mechanical time-clocks that stamped the information on a physical card - but since your employer probably issues these numbers to employees "for life", there are still employees who were allocated a "clock number" before computer-based accounting started!

Comment: **Your P60** should also clearly indicate your 'payroll number' or whatever, as well as the tax district (may be 'Employer PAYE reference)